# Dell Latitude 5480 wireless not working

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, dell

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a laptop Dell latitude 4580. I have a Bluetooth that work good, but when I try to turn on the wifi I don't get nothing.

```
mohammed@mohammed:~$ sudo nmcli device
[sudo] password for mohammed: 
DEVICE     TYPE      STATE      CONNECTION        
enp0s31f6  ethernet  connected  netplan-enp0s31f6 
lo         loopback  unmanaged  --
```

and for the output of `lshw -businfo` command:

```
Bus info          Device     Class          Description
=======================================================
                         system         Latitude 5480 (07A7)
                         bus            05Y099
                         memory         64KiB BIOS
                         memory         16GiB System Memory
                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
                         memory         8GiB SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 2400 MHz (0.4 ns)
                         memory         128KiB L1 cache
                         memory         512KiB L2 cache
                         memory         3MiB L3 cache
cpu@0                        processor      Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-7300U CPU @ 2.60GHz
pci@0000:00:00.0             bridge         Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor 
Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
pci@0000:00:02.0             display        HD Graphics 620
pci@0000:00:04.0             generic        Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core 
Processor Thermal Subsystem
pci@0000:00:14.0             bus            Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller
usb@1             usb1       bus            xHCI Host Controller
usb@1:3                      multimedia     CPH1989
usb@1:5                      multimedia     Integrated_Webcam_HD
usb@1:7                      communication  Bluetooth wireless interface
usb@1:8                      input          LGDisplay Incell Touch
usb@1:a                      generic        5880
usb@2             usb2       bus            xHCI Host Controller
pci@0000:00:14.2             generic        Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem
pci@0000:00:15.0             generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0
pci@0000:00:15.1             generic        Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1
pci@0000:00:16.0             communication  Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1
pci@0000:00:17.0             storage        Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
pci@0000:00:1c.0             bridge         Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1
pci@0000:01:00.0             generic        RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader
pci@0000:00:1f.0             bridge         Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller
pci@0000:00:1f.2             memory         Memory controller
pci@0000:00:1f.3             multimedia     Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio
pci@0000:00:1f.4             bus            Sunrise Point-LP SMBus
pci@0000:00:1f.6  enp0s31f6  network        Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
                             system         PnP device PNP0b00
                             generic        PnP device INT3f0d
                             input          PnP device PNP0303
                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
                             system         PnP device PNP0c02
                  scsi2      storage        
scsi@2:0.0.0      /dev/sda   disk           256GB SK hynix SC311 S
scsi@2:0.0.0,1    /dev/sda1  volume         127MiB reserved partition
scsi@2:0.0.0,2    /dev/sda2  volume         99MiB Windows FAT volume
scsi@2:0.0.0,3    /dev/sda3  volume         15EiB Windows FAT volume
scsi@2:0.0.0,4    /dev/sda4  volume         94MiB EFI partition
scsi@2:0.0.0,5    /dev/sda5  volume         3906MiB EXT4 volume
scsi@2:0.0.0,6    /dev/sda6  volume         2940MiB Linux swap volume
scsi@2:0.0.0,7    /dev/sda7  volume         102GiB EXT4 volume
                             power          DELL DJWGP9C
```

***Edit***
the output of `sudo lshw -c network`:

```
  sudo lshw -c network
    *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 21
       serial: a4:4c:c8:15:e7:87
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.13.0-37-generic duplex=full firmware=0.1-4 ip=192.168.1.14 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:129 memory:ef100000-ef11ffff
```

and the commande `sudo lspci`:

```
sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v6/7th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 02)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 02)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Thermal subsystem (rev 21)
00:15.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 21)
00:15.1 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 21)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP CSME HECI #1 (rev 21)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 21)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point LPC Controller/eSPI Controller (rev 21)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP PMC (rev 21)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio (rev 21)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP SMBus (rev 21)
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (4) I219-LM (rev 21)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

and:

```
sudo lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 1fd2:6004 Melfas LGDisplay Incell Touch
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 1bcf:2b96 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Integrated_Webcam_HD
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a5c:5833 Broadcom Corp. 5880
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include the output of: (1) `sudo lshw -c network` (2) `sudo lspci` and (3) `sudo lsusb`? This should show some specific information about the wireless device, allowing for a solution to be provided 

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 20.04 usually works fine on the Dell 5480 (I'm using one now).
This may seem too obvious, but,it looks to me from the output that wifi is not showing because ethernet is connected. Unplug the ethernet and try again!